# Is it possible to use NH QueryOver to fetch joined entities in one query?

Tags: sql, nhibernate, inner-join, queryover

SQL query is:

```
select B.* from A inner join B on A.b_id = B.id where A.x in (1,2,3)
```

A <-> B relation is many-to-one

I need to filter by A but fetch related B.

UPDATE:

I tried this NH QueryOver

```
Session.QueryOver<A>.Where(a => a.x.IsIn(array)).JoinQueryOver(a => a.B).Select(a => a.B).List<B>()
```

but it results in a N+1 sequence of queries: the first one fetches IDs of related Bs, and others fetch related Bs one by one by ID (analyzed via NHProf). I want it to fetch a list of Bs in one go.

UPDATE 2:

for now I worked around this with subquery

```
Session.QueryOver(() => b).WithSubquery.WhereExists(QueryOver.Of<A>().Where(a => a.x.IsIn(array)).And(a => a.b_id == b.id).Select(a => a.id)).List<B>()
```

but I still hope to see an example of QueryOver *without* subquery as I tend to think subquery is less efficient.

Comment: Yes it is possible, I think you at least should give it a go first!

Comment: Try to add a Fetch(a=>a.B).Eager after Where(a => a.x.IsIn(array)) to get rid of the N+1 problem.

Comment: @AndreLoker it didn't help, the same problem.

Comment: Subquery, should be the way, how to get filtered set of `B` based on any filters form A... and so on

Answer (score 3):

This works (at least in my test application):

```
var list = session.QueryOver<A>()
                    .Where(a => a.X.IsIn(array))
                    .Fetch(x => x.B).Eager
                    .List<A>()
                    .Select(x => x.B);
```

Note that the .Select() statement is a normal LINQ statement, not part of NHibernate.

Generated SQL:

```
SELECT 
  this_.Id as Id0_1_, 
  this_.B as B0_1_, 
  this_.X as X0_1_, 
  b2_.Id as Id1_0_, 
  b2_.SomeValue as SomeValue1_0_ 
FROM A this_ left outer join B b2_ on this_.B=b2_.Id 
WHERE this_.X in (?, ?, ?)
```

It's not optimal if A is a very large class, of course.

An NHibernate-only solution with a subquery:

```
var candidates = QueryOver.Of<A>()
                            .Where(a => a.X.IsIn(array))
                            .Select(x => x.B.Id);

var list = session.QueryOver<B>()
                    .WithSubquery.WhereProperty(x => x.Id).In(candidates).List();
```

I'll try to find the reason why the most obvious solution (just adding Fetch().Eager) doesn't work as expected. Stay tuned!

Comment: option with eager association fetching and LINQ-ing is a really good alternative for subquery in some cases, thanks!